# SQL Case Statement Increasing Runtime Exponentially

Tags: sql-server, function, case, implementation

I have a query that seems to be taking an inordinate amount of time.  I have narrowed it down to the CASE Statements, I have 7 similar statements in the query.  Without the 7 CASE statements it takes 40sec to run on 15,700 records
I ran a very similar query on the customers, but they only had one name/address/city/state/zip, but it took 10min to run for over 4,000 records.  I'm over 6hrs for this query and something doesn't seem right.  I don't know if it's the CASE statement itself, or the function I'm calling in it.  It probably doesn't help that I call the function twice, one in the EXISTS, and again to get the value.  I included the function so if there is something I missed there, I'd appreciate letting me know.

This version of one of the CASE statements takes 31s to run for 100 records:

```
CASE
    -- Populated and Confirmed; Return City Untouched
    WHEN ( ( uc.[City] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[City] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [City] = uc.[cleanCity] ) )
        THEN uc.[cleanCity]  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched

    -- No Match Found
    ELSE uc.[City]
END AS [City]
```

However, this version takes 10m 31s to run for the same 100 records:
I included the SQL plan for this run [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJDVpCD1t)

```
CASE
    -- Populated and Confirmed; Return City Untouched
    WHEN ( ( uc.[City] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[City] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [City] = uc.[cleanCity] ) )
        THEN uc.[cleanCity]  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched

    -- Attempt to determine from State, Zip, Country
    WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) ) )
        THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [City] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) )  -- Match Found; Return Match

    -- No Match Found
    ELSE uc.[City]
END AS [City]
```

The uc ([Cleansed_Vendors]) table has the same fields as the query, the query is basically creating a cleansed copy of the table.  All but VendorID are varchar.  I have a Non-Clustered Indicies on all [City], [cleanCity], [State], [Zip] and [Country] on the uc table.

Here is the fn_LocationInfo, and the full query with all the case statements is below it:
The [CityStateInfo] has all the same fields and type as the ReturnTable.  There is a Non-Clustered Index on each of the fields in the [CityStateInfo] table.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo] (@mode int, @inCity varchar(255), @inState varchar(255), @inZip varchar(255), @inCountry varchar(255))
    RETURNS @returnTable TABLE (
        [city]          varchar(255) NULL,
        [state_abbr]    varchar(255) NULL,
        [state_long]    varchar(255) NULL,
        [zip]           varchar(255) NULL,
        [country]       varchar(255) NULL,
        [country_abbr]  varchar(255) NULL,
        [county]        varchar(255) NULL,
        [longitude]     varchar(255) NULL,
        [latitude]      varchar(255) NULL
    )
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

    -- Cleans and Sets Values
    IF (@inCity IS NULL) OR (@inCity = '')
        SET @inCity = NULL
    ELSE
        SET @inCity = TRIM(@inCity)

    IF (@inState IS NULL) OR (@inState = '')
        SET @inState = NULL
    ELSE
        SET @inState = TRIM(@inState)

    IF (@inZip IS NULL) OR (@inZip = '')
        SET @inZip = NULL
    ELSE
        SET @inZip = TRIM(@inZip)

    IF (@inCountry IS NULL) OR (@inCountry = '')
        SET @inCountry = NULL
    ELSE
        SET @inCountry = TRIM(@inCountry)


    IF (@inCountry = 'US') OR (@inCountry = 'USA')
        SET @inCountry = 'United States'
    IF (@inCountry = 'CA') OR (@inCountry = 'CAD')
        SET @inCountry = 'Canada'

    IF (  LEN(@inZip) = 10 )
        SET @inZip = LEFT(@inZip,5)



    -- Returns the First Set of Values Found
    INSERT INTO @returnTable
        SELECT TOP(1) 
            [City], 
            [State_abbr], 
            [State_long], 
            [Zip], 
            [Country], 
            [Country_abbr], 
            [County], 
            [Longitude], 
            [Latitude]
          FROM [CityStateInfo]
          WHERE
            (   -- Everything entered, looking for verification
                @inCity IS NOT NULL AND
                @inState IS NOT NULL AND
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inCountry IS NOT NULL
                AND 
                [City] = @inCity AND 
                ( [State_abbr] = @inState OR [State_long] = @inState) AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip AND 
                [Country] = @inCountry 
            )
            OR
            (   -- Zip Code, Country: Will find City and State  /* BEST RESULTS */
                @inCity IS NULL AND
                @inState IS NULL AND
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inCountry IS NOT NULL
                AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip AND 
                [Country] = @inCountry 
            )
            OR
            (   -- City, Zip Code, Country: Will find State 
                @inCity IS NOT NULL AND
                @inState IS NULL AND
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inCountry IS NOT NULL
                AND 
                [City] = @inCity AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip AND 
                [Country] = @inCountry 
            )
            OR
            (   -- State, Zip Code, Country: Will find City 
                @inCity IS NULL AND
                @inState IS NOT NULL AND
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inCountry IS NOT NULL
                AND 
                ( [State_abbr] = @inState OR [State_long] = @inState) AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip AND 
                [Country] = @inCountry 
            )
            OR
            (   -- State, Zip Code: Will find State , Country
                @inCity     IS NULL AND
                @inState    IS NOT NULL AND
                @inZip      IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inCountry  IS NULL
                AND 
                ( [State_abbr] = @inState OR [State_long] = @inState) AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip 
            )
            OR
            (   -- City, State, Country:  Will find first Zip Code in City, State
                @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inState IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inZip IS NULL AND
                @inCountry IS NOT NULL 
                AND 
                [City] = @inCity AND 
                ( [State_abbr] = @inState OR [State_long] = @inState) AND 
                [Country] = @inCountry 
            )
            OR
            (   -- City, State: Will find first Zip Code in City, State. Will find Country
                @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inState IS NOT NULL AND
                @inZip IS NULL AND 
                @inCountry IS NULL
                AND 
                [City] = @inCity AND 
                ( [State_abbr] = @inState OR [State_long] = @inState)
            )
            OR          

            
            (   -- City, State, Zip: Will find Country
                @inCity IS NOT NULL AND
                @inState IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND
                @inCountry IS NULL 
                AND 
                [City] = @inCity AND
                ( [State_abbr] = @inState OR [State_long] = @inState) AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip
            )


            OR
            (   -- City, Zip:  Will find State and Country
                @inCity IS NOT NULL AND 
                @inState IS NULL AND
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND
                @inCountry IS NULL
                AND 
                [City] = @inCity AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip
            )
            OR
            (   -- State, Zip:  Will find City and Country
                @inCity IS NULL AND 
                @inState IS NOT NULL AND
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND
                @inCountry IS NULL 
                AND 
                ( [State_abbr] = @inState OR [State_long] = @inState) AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip
            )
            OR
            (
                -- Zip Code: Will find City, State and Country  ** Possible error if Country is not US or Canada
                @inCity IS NULL AND
                @inState IS NULL AND
                @inZip IS NOT NULL AND
                @inCountry IS NULL
                AND 
                [Zip] = @inZip 
            )
    RETURN
END














SELECT TOP(100)
    uc.[Company],
    uc.[VendorID],

    (SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_strNorm](2, uc.[Vendor Name])) AS [Vendor Name],
    (SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_strNorm](1,(SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_NormalizeUSPS](uc.[Address1])))) AS [Address1],
    (SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_strNorm](1,(SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_NormalizeUSPS](uc.[Address2])))) AS [Address2],
                
    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return City Untouched
        WHEN ( ( uc.[City] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[City] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [City] = uc.[cleanCity] ) )
            THEN uc.[cleanCity]  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched

        -- Attempt to determine from State, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [City] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) )  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[City]
    END AS [City],

    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return Correctly Formatted State to Eliminate Format Issues
        WHEN ( ( uc.[State] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[State] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [State_abbr] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [State_abbr] = uc.[State] OR [State_long] = uc.[State] ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [State_abbr] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [State_abbr] = uc.[State] OR [State_long] = uc.[State] )  -- Data Confirmed; Returns Correctly Formatted State

        -- Attempt to determine from City, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [State_abbr] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, [cleanCity], uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) ) )
            THEN ( SELECT [City] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], NULL, uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) )  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[State]
    END AS [State],
            
    CASE
        -- Populated, US or Canadian Formatted and Confirmed; Return Zip Untouched
        WHEN ( ( uc.[Zip] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[Zip] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [Zip] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE ( (LEN(uc.[Zip]) = 5 OR LEN(uc.[Zip]) = 10) AND [Zip] = LEFT(uc.[Zip], 5) ) OR ( LEN(uc.[Zip]) = 7 AND [Zip] = uc.[Zip] ) ) )
            THEN uc.[Zip]   -- Data Confirmed, Return Zip Untouched
                    
        -- Attempt to determine from City, State, Country
        WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [Zip] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], NULL, uc.[Country]) ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [Zip] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], NULL, uc.[Country]) )  -- Match Found; Return Match
                    
        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[Zip]
    END AS [Zip],
            
    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return Country Untouched
        WHEN ( uc.[Country] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[Country] <> '') AND EXISTS( SELECT [Country] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [Country] = uc.[Country] )
            THEN uc.[Country]

        -- Attempt to determine from City, State, Zip
        WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [Country] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], uc.[Zip], NULL) ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [Country] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], uc.[Zip], NULL) )
                    
        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[Country]
    END AS [Country],

        /****    PO Address    ****/

    (SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_strNorm](2, uc.[Vendor Name_P])) AS [Vendor Name_P],
    (SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_strNorm](1,(SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_NormalizeUSPS](uc.[Address1_P])))) AS [Address1_P],
    (SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_strNorm](1,(SELECT strNew FROM [dbo].[fn_NormalizeUSPS](uc.[Address2_P])))) AS [Address2_P],
                
    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return City Untouched
        WHEN ( ( uc.[City_P] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[City_P] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [City] = uc.[cleanCity_P] ) )
            THEN uc.[cleanCity_P]  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched

        -- Attempt to determine from State, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State_P], uc.[Zip_P], NULL) ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [City] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State_P], uc.[Zip_P], NULL) )  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[City_P]
    END AS [City_P],

    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return Correctly Formatted State to Eliminate Format Issues
        WHEN ( ( uc.[State_P] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[State_P] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [State_abbr] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [State_abbr] = uc.[State_P] OR [State_long] = uc.[State_P] ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [State_abbr] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE [State_abbr] = uc.[State_P] OR [State_long] = uc.[State_P] )  -- Data Confirmed; Returns Correctly Formatted State

        -- Attempt to determine from City, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [State_abbr] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity_P], NULL, uc.[Zip_P], NULL) ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [State_abbr] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity_P], NULL, uc.[Zip_P], NULL) )  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[State_P]
    END AS [State_P],
            
    CASE
        -- Populated, US or Canadian Formatted and Confirmed; Return Zip Untouched
        WHEN ( ( uc.[Zip_P] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[Zip_P] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [Zip] FROM [CityStateInfo] WHERE ( (LEN(uc.[Zip_P]) = 5 OR LEN(uc.[Zip_P]) = 10) AND [Zip] = LEFT(uc.[Zip_P], 5) ) OR ( LEN(uc.[Zip_P]) = 7 AND [Zip] = uc.[Zip_P] ) ) )
            THEN uc.[Zip_P] -- Data Confirmed, Return Zip Untouched
        
        -- Attempt to determine from City, State, Country
        WHEN ( EXISTS( SELECT [Zip] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity_P], uc.[State_P], NULL, NULL) ) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [Zip] FROM [dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity_P], uc.[State_P], NULL, NULL) )  -- Match Found; Return Match
                    
        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[Zip_P]
    END AS [Zip_P],
            
    uc.[Phone1],
    uc.[Phone1_P],
    uc.[Phone2],
    uc.[Phone3],

    uc.[MRO_Flag],
    uc.[LegalName],
    
    (TRIM( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE([City], '''', ''), '.', ''), ',', '') ) ) AS [cleanCity],
    (TRIM( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE([City_P], '''', ''), '.', ''), ',', '') ) ) AS [cleanCity_P]
    
    FROM [Cleansed_Vendors] uc
ORDER BY [Company], [VendorID]






CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CityStateInfo](
    [City] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [State_abbr] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [State_long] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [County] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Longitude] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Latitude] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [StateFIPS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CountryFIPS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TimeZone] [int] NULL,
    [cleanCity] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Country_abbr] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_CITY]            ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_cleanCity]       ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([cleanCity] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_City_Zip]        ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_City_State]      ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC, [State_abbr] ASC, [State_long] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_City_State_Zip]  ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC, [State_abbr] ASC, [State_long] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_STATE_LONG]      ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([State_long] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_STATE_ABBR]      ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([State_abbr] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_State_Zip]       ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([State_abbr] ASC, [State_long] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_ZIP]             ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_COUNTY]          ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([County] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_COUNTRY]         ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([Country] ASC)
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server so I will tag accordingly. When you mix procedural things like functions with set based operations, things really slow down

Comment: Clearly it's your `exists` that is (one) problem, it looks like you have no indexes on your tables, plus your functions are multi-statement table-valued funtions which will not be performant and doing RBAR processing.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yeah, I just dont understand why it's 100x slower on this data set vs the customer.  It has 2x the fields, so even if it was 4x slower I would understand, but it JUST finished.  7hr 18min.

Comment: @stu I had a feeling it was the `exists` but I can't see a way to cover the cases I need without adding several more condition statements to each case.  All my tables involved have indexes.  I'm open to ideas on how to improve the function, usage of the function or the processing.

Comment: You have a whole bunch of UDF's in there. They are killers for performance. Especially the one that you've posted. Are you trying to cleanse and fuzzy match data on the fly? You're better off at least cleansing it properly and saving it

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Your query is performing table scans so it looks like your tables are *heaps* without any clustered indexes, the exists check on `CityStateInfo` is reading all 2,033,805,979 rows in order to return just 2k rows and together with a table spool is about 80% of the overall query cost.

Comment: Just looking at your function it's a performance nightmare with `or` conditions over different columns, also you have a `top(1)` and no `order by` - so this will effectively give you a random row.

Comment: Also FYI `CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(255),[ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo].[City],0)=[uc].[cleanCity]` is not helping.

Comment: There are so many things wrong here it's hard to know where to start. Using `OUTER APPLY` on your functions will at least prevent them being called more than once per row. You are trying to do too many things with that function, make separate functions for each combination of search parameters, instead of all those `OR`. Change it into an inline Table Function (single `SELECT`, no table variable), this will be much faster. `TOP` without `ORDER BY` doesn't really make sense. Index your tables properly.

Comment: @stu I'd kill for a proper chat with you about now :)  Is that 2b ?!  Yeah, there are 946,142 rows in that table, why is it reading over 2b??  I THOUGHT I had created proper indexes, but I admit I'm not great with them.  I added the table definition and indexes at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @stu Odd, the original source for [cleanCity] is varchar(255).  I did a SELECT INTO the uc table and it was changed to nvarchar(4000).  The largest value is 22 chars, so not sure why it would do that.

Comment: @Charlieface I like the idea of the `OUTER APPLY`.  I see what you are saying with breaking up the function, but I can't because there are too many variables in the data itself.  If I send a NULL value into the function for a variable, then I'll get nothing back, but if the variable that had the NULL was not considered, I would get results.  I'd need `OR` or `CASE` somewhere to sort that out, in the function or before it

Comment: It's doing an implicit conversion because you are comparing `CityStateInfo` and `cleanCity` and one of those is `varchar` and one `nvarchar`. I suggest you maybe split the query up completely, look at [Kitchen Sink Queries](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example), perhaps consider `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: I don't know why it changed the type for cleanCity but I got that fixed and runs much better.  I am getting another one though where one is nvarchar(10) and the other is nvarchar(255). Makes no sense.

Comment: @Stu I added a a Clustered Index to [CityStateInfo] and used `OUTER APPLY` for the function.  Made a HUGE difference for the City `CASE` expression.  I added the State `CASE` expression and my basic query is killing it. `SELECT TOP(1) [state_abbr] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [state_abbr] = uc.[State] OR [state_long] = uc.[State] ORDER BY [state_abbr]`  I can't join the [CityStateInfo] table because it would have multiple matches for everything.  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyMlPFu1t

Comment: @Charlieface Good call on the `OUTER APPLY`.  Adding the clustered Index and using the `OUTER APPLY` took the one query down to 5s for all 15k records!  Adding the state `CASE` expression takes the runtime from 5s to 10m31s as I noted in above comment.

Comment: When it comes to using `or` criteria, often (not always, depending on the optimizer's ability to use index intersection), better performance can be obtained by two seperate queries unioned together, with a non-clustered index on each searched column.

Comment: I just don't get why you are using all those `CASE WHEN EXISTS...SELECT...` just put it in an `OUTER APPLY` then it defaults to null if there is no result